# Issue in the declaration of functions on SlimPhp

Tags: php, rest, slim

It's just since I started to discover slim and I ran into a problem, I do not know how to look for a solution because it is very strange. 
Basically if I declare a function that is called from the route after another function is also called by a route, the first is not performed.

API group

```
// API group
$app->group('/api/:key', function () use ($app) {

    //print all route
    $app->get('/all',function () use($app){
        echoRoutes();
    });
    // Library group
    $app->group('/themer', function () use ($app) {

         //get number of subscribed themer
        $app->get('/count','allowed',function (){
            echo "ciao";
        });
        //get information about the themer selected
        $app->get('/:id','getThemer'); //AFTER THIS ROUTES /ciao AND /themes NOT WORK

         $app->get('/ciao',function () use($app){
        echoRoutes();
    });

     // Get book with ID
        $app->get('/themes', function () use ($app) {
            $articles = R::findAll('users'); 
            $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            echo json_encode(R::exportAll($articles));
        });

        //get number of submitted theme by themer
        //$app->get('/:id/themes','getSubmitedThemeById');


        //get information about selected theme
        //$app->get('/:id/themes/:theme','getThemeById');

        $app->get('/themes/:id/', function ($id) {
            $articles = R::find("users","id = ?",[$id]);
            echo json_encode(R::exportAll($articles));
        });

    });

});
```

external file with function

```
//external file with function
function  getThemer($key,$id) { 
   $themer = R::find("themers","id = ?",[$id]);
   echo json_encode(R::exportAll($themer));
   return true;
}

function countThemer(){
    echo "count";
    $count =  R::exec( 'SELECT COUNT(id) FROM themers' );
    echo $count;
}

function allowed($key){
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $params = $app->router()->getCurrentRoute()->getParams();
    if(!($params["key"]=="giulio"))
        $app->redirect ("http://google.com");

}
```

after the route **index.php/api/giulio/themer/1** that call getThemer and work the route **index.php/api/giulio/themer/ciao** and **index.php/api/giulio/themer/themes** not work

I thank you in advance for possible help 
criticism or comments on the code in 'general appearance are welcome

Comment: So you use the route index.php/api/giulio/themer/1 and want 3 different routes to be executed?

Comment: index.php/api/giulio/themer is a group of route , then the route inside should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the routes:

```
// API group
$app->group('/api/:key', function () use ($app) {

    //print all route
    $app->get('/all',function () use($app){
        echoRoutes();
    });
    // Library group
    $app->group('/themer', function () use ($app) {

         //get number of subscribed themer
        $app->get('/count','allowed',function (){
            echo "ciao";
        });

        $app->get('/ciao',function () use($app){
            echoRoutes();
        });

        // Get book with ID
        $app->get('/themes', function () use ($app) {
            $articles = R::findAll('users');
            $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            echo json_encode(R::exportAll($articles));
        });

        //get number of submitted theme by themer
        //$app->get('/:id/themes','getSubmitedThemeById');


        //get information about selected theme
        //$app->get('/:id/themes/:theme','getThemeById');

        $app->get('/themes/:id/', function ($id) {
            $articles = R::find("users","id = ?",[$id]);
            echo json_encode(R::exportAll($articles));
        });

        //get information about the themer selected
        $app->get('/:id','getThemer');

    });

});
```

Comment: I also had temporarily solved so but because that order is not good ?

Comment: I think that slim just add all the url patterns in the same order you give. If you put the generic /:id before all the others, it will match in every case, for every name.

Comment: @LorenzoSalani if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.